# Getting error while starting Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Tags: boot, startup

I recently made the switch to ubuntu and have been working around adding packages and all. Now, during startup I encounter the following error always.

```
Error found when loading /home/usr/.profile:
/home/usr/.profile:line 29: E:: command not found
/home/usr/.profile:line 30: Try: command not found
As a result the session will not be configured correctly.
You should fix the problem as soon as feasible.
```

Any possible solution to this. Thanks in advance.

my .profile file looks like this ,

```
# ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
# This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
# exists.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files for examples.
# the files are located in the bash-doc package.

# the default umask is set in /etc/profile; for setting the umask
# for ssh logins, install and configure the libpam-umask package.
#umask 022

# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/.local/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
fi
eval $(E: Linuxbrew directory detected, but it seems broken.
   Try to remove '/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew' and install again./bin/brew shellenv)
```

Comment: Yes, fix the errors in line 29 and 30 in .profile. Or at least, update the question with the content of .profile so some one here can have a look at it.

Comment: I gather you've changed your $USER (username) to be 'usr'  (/usr/ is a special directory in unix) - but look at your .profile file & correct errors on lines 29 and 30.  We can't see those lines, so can't see what you've done to them (but I'd hope it would be obvious; turning the lines into comments ("# " at start of those lines) would be easiest fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `terminal`...

```
gedit /home/usr/.profile
```

Open gedit preferences, and enable line numbering...

[image]

Locate lines 29-30.

Copy lines 25-35 to the clipboard.

Edit your question here, paste in the clipboard, select the pasted text, hit the {} icon to make the text human readable.

I'll look at it and suggest a fix.

**Update #1:**

Remove the two lines at the end of .profile...

```
eval $(E: Linuxbrew directory detected, but it seems broken.
   Try to remove '/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew' and install again./bin/brew shellenv)
```

Comment: Did it sir. Kindly look into it.